# Xcode Debugger stops if I quit the iOS simulator after clicking the Home button

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I've noticed this weird behaviour, with virtually any (well 5 different) Xcode/iOS project I'm debugging.

1. From Xcode (4.0.2) Run the project (into iOS simulator)
2. In the simulator, click the Home button.
3. Quit the simulator (by Cmd+Q)

==> The Xcode enters the debugger, and the stack trace shows:
mach_msg_trp
UIApplicationMain
main

The weird thing is that if I slightly alter the sequence, as follows:
1. From Xcode (4.0.2) Run the project (into iOS simulator)
2. In the simulator, click the Home button.
3. Click my application icon (the one I'm debugging) on the iOS simulator
4. Quit the simulator (by Cmd+Q)

==> No problem...

Anyone else experience this?
Any idea what this is and what's causing it?

Thanks

Comment: i did'nt get your point of issue, will you plz elaborate it.

Comment: Of course a bit strange. Are these 5 projects made by you, i.e. maybe there is a copy & paste bug in your background handling? Have you tried it using one of Apple's sample projects?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project? `Cmd+Shift+K`

Comment: [to iphonePlayer:] My issue is that for some reason, the debugger seems to report a problem if (and only if) I quit the simulator after clicking the home button. Any other workflow works fine.

Comment: [to marzapower:] yes, I have tried Cmd+Shift+K

Comment: [to Kay:] one project was/is a fresh project from the Xcode templates...

Answer (score 0):

It's not weird, just the way how xcode debug works.. When you start for debug it just link the debug session with instance running on the simulator.. So if you press home button, it stops debugging session because at that time there is no app running on ios.

Comment: Thanks - but then why is Xcode entering the debugger, as if my app crashed?

Comment: I dont know actually why it's entering the debugger but it does not mean that your app is crashing..

Comment: Did yo get solution i have same issue>?